# Getting problem in using different pointer variable for head if we try to modify original head of linked list using a function in call by reference

Tags: c, function, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I tried to do insertion in linked list by passing it to a function using pointer to pointer call(call by reference). I tried using a different variable for head pointer within the function, but insertion doesn't takes place due to use of that variable at some places (as mentioned in the code below). If i use *head in place of hd at the below mentioned position the code runs successfully.
Why this problem arises?

```
**EXPLAINED MY PROBLEM AND QUESTION IN THE CODE BELOW**

typedef struct ll {
    int data;
    struct ll *next;
}list;

**insert(&head,&n);  this is used in main() for insertion**

**FUNCTION FOR INSERTION IN LINKED LIST**
void insert(list **head,int *n)  **n=size of linked list**
{
    list *hd;  
     hd=*head;   **i am trying to use this variable for convenience**

      int pos,i,value;
    list *ins,*t;
    
    printf("\nenter position to insert ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    
    if(pos>(*n+1) || pos<1)
    {
    printf("\ninvalid position\n");
    return;
    }
    
    printf("enter value to insert ");
    scanf("%d",&value);

    ins=(list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    ins->data=value; 
    
    if(pos==1)  
    {
       ins->next=hd;   **hd can be used here**

       *head=ins;   ***this is the problem postion***
                **if i use hd=ins here then no insertion takes place,why?**
**but if i use *head=ins as used then code runs successfully.**
               
                        
    }
    
      else 
    {
    
    for(i=1;i<pos-1;i++)  **BUT IN THIS BLOCK ALSO ,I CAN USE hd i.e. not neccessary to use *head **
    {
        hd=(hd->next);
    }
                t=hd;
        hd=(hd->next);
        t->next=ins;
        ins->next=hd;
    
        
    }

  *n=*n+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your "list" in "insert" is exist in "insert" only and drops after exiting from it. It needed or copy the added structure in already existing sequence and correct the pointers or provide empty place in the array with sequence or ti increase this array before inserting and in any case correct pointers. And I prefer two-relation list.

Comment: Actually, the code runs successfully if the variable hd is not used in place of *head at the specified position. I have re-edited my question part for better understanding of my concern. Please refer to it.  I would also like to know more about your preference of "two relation list"

Comment: In any case memory for the new element must be allocate in main, where the whole array is used. I means that the structure can include pointer or address to previous element and tho next. Also if in subroutine use malloc() it must call free() before exiting.